# .NET Core 2.1 API Kestrel problems when stress testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have an API developed in .NET Core 2.1 and while doing stress testing, it reports a Kestrel web server error and I don't know what it is.

The error message is: *Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.*

I leave the call stack I see in the Application Insights log.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody+d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
>      at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
>      at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
>      at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe+DefaultPipeReader.GetResult (System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody+<ReadAsync>d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream+d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream+<ReadAsync>d__35.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions+d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter+d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=2.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder+<BindModelAsync>d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder+<BindModelAsync>d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware+d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at quodem_qcore_gamification.api.Startup+<>c+<b__5_0>d.MoveNext (quodem-qcore-gamification.api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware+d__8.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware+d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol+d__188`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error message is: Reading the request body timed out due to data
>   arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.

I suggest you can take a look at the source code of [`KestrelHttpServer`](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/tree/68a08635244df0941b5edd4cc07b2fd0a3cbddcd) and add the following code in `Configure` method in the startup file:

```
app.UseKestrel(opt =>
{
opt.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
})
```